# counterexample to 4-color theorem must contain no separating 4-cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

In Graph Theory by Bondy and Murty, on page 397, the following is left as an exercise (to prove both of them):

($G$ is a minimal counterexample to the 4-color theorem)

Theorem: $G$ contains no separating 4-cycle.

Corollary $G$ is 5-connected.

But I don't know how to start with either, someone help? Thank you!

Comment: Start with the definitions of "separating $4$-cycle" and "$5$-connected."

Comment: I realize that seems sarcastic, but given no context of the book other than the exercise, it is hard for us to know where to start. What is the context/chapter? What are the definitions of these terms?

Comment: In particular, googling *graph theory separating cycle* yields no basic math page like a Wikipedia article, starting instead with scholarly articles. So without definitions, you are greatly limiting who can help you. Help people help you.